# Carbon parse to ISO8601

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am trying to get the current time and format it like:

```
"2018-09-26T21:40:29+02:00"
```

But when I try:

```
$isoDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('c');
```

as I understood passing a `c` to format function will parse it to iso8601 but clearly thats not the case.

Any help on how to parse current time to `ISO8601 OR 20181001T094006Z`

Comment: There's no single 8601 format.  Construct it yourself with the date formats.

Comment: @Devon https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: What happens when you try what you have? `c` should translate to ISO8601. Here's what I get when I run `echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format("c");`: 2018-09-26T20:05:30+00:00

Comment: @AladinSmall, yes, and there are about 8 different formats there...

Comment: @Devon i think I am very constructive on my question, however due to my poor reputation I am a good catch for trolling. So please read the question again its specified what kind of iso format : ***ISO8601 OR 20181001T094006Z***

Comment: Did you atleast try to read the format manual and construct it yourself using existing characters like `YmdTHisZ`

Comment: @miken32 I did tried but I get this : `2018-09-26T21:40:29+02:00` which is not acceptable from the web service that I am trying to sent, as they want smth like: 20181001T094006Z . I mean I know the ugly way of parsing it that way by extracting year month .... and concat but It must be smth that I am missing.

Comment: That's exactly what you're looking for, according to your question...

Comment: @Devon do u know what should I pass in order to get the correct format ?

Comment: What output *did* you get?

Comment: @Devon that was it `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('YmdTHisZ')` I get: `"20180926CEST2216517200"` thats what I need to know so add the answer to mark the question as problem solved. thanks.

Comment: Ok, so T and Z are format characters so escaping them with a backslash should work

Comment: @Devon works. thanks finally on the same frequency.

Comment: Consider changing accepted answer.  Nurdin's answer works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no single 8601 format.  8601 defines various acceptable formats, of which PHP's `c` represents one of the most common forms.

There is no single character for the specific 8601 format you wish but a format of `Ymd\THis\Z` should work.   `T` and `Z`are literal, so escape them with a backslash to avoid them being interpreted in the format string.  Be sure that only UTC timestamps are used with this particular format.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php lists all the acceptable format characters.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid ISO 8601 format? I don't think the hyphens between year, month and date are optional neither the colons between hour, minute and seconds.

Comment: Yes.  Like I said in the answer and comments, 8601 has multiple formats.

Answer (score 48):

```
Carbon::now()->toISOString()
```

this will return
`2020-05-12T13:13:42.817684Z`

```
Carbon::now()->toIso8601String()
```

this will return
`2020-05-12T13:15:32+00:00`

using corePHP

```
date(DateTime::ATOM, time())
```

this will return
`2021-08-22T15:26:48+10:00`

Answer (score 37):

```
echo Carbon::now()->toIso8601String();
```